# install scikit-learn for python 3.3 on windows 7

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.3

I am really new to the use of Python and the associated packages that can be installed.
As a biologist I am looking for a lot of new packages that would help me model species systems, ecological change etc.. and after a lot of "Google-ing" I came across scikit-learn.
However, I am having trouble installing it. And I will take this moment now to apologise for the length of this post.

I am using 64bit Python 3.3 and have the associated NumPy (MKL 1.7.0) and SciPy. I installed distribute which worked fine and allows me to use easy_install.
So to install scikit-learn, I tried using the cmd prompt (Windows) run in administrator mode, and then also through Python command line.
I placed the downloaded and extracted tar.gz file in the Lib\site-packages folder.
When I run the command
     `easy_install scikit-learn`
in cmd prompt.
Then this is the following output:

```
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages>easy_install -U scikit-learn
Searching for scikit-learn
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/
Reading http://scikit-learn.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/scikit-learn/files/
Reading http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net
Best match: scikit-learn 0.12.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0
.12.1.tar.gz#md5=7e8b3434f9e8198b82dc3774f8bc9394
Processing scikit-learn-0.12.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\nuvraj~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-kvr2q0\scikit-learn-0.
12.1\setup.cfg
Running scikit-learn-0.12.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\nuvraj~1\a
ppdata\local\temp\easy_install-kvr2q0\scikit-learn-0.12.1\egg-dist-tmp-l618ie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.33', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1937, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1918, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1941, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
358, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
598, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
628, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
823, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1103, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1089, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 34, in run_se
tup
    lambda: exec(compile(open(
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 82, in run
    return func()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 37, in <lambd
a>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'})
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nuvraj~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-kvr2q0\scikit-learn-0.
12.1\sklearn\__init__.py", line 86
    print "I: Seeding RNGs with %r" % _random_seed
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages>
```

So the little ^ seems to be pointing at the " after RNGS with %r. Which from what I can tell is in the '*init*' file from the sklearn folder found in the .tar.gz file.

I also get the same result when running it in the Python GUI and command line.

How can I install scikit-learn with Python 3.3? Is there some way of building it or editing the file to get past this invalid syntax error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And I am very sorry for it being such a long post. I was just trying to get all the details in there.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 2):

scikit-learn does not support Python 3 yet. For now you need Python 2.7.

Proper support for Python 3 is expected for the 0.14 release scheduled for Q2-2013.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will keep checking for the updated version and thanks for all the hard work

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but in my understanding the print statement in Python 3.* is now a function, called like: print(). So, a quick solution in this case is to change

```
print "I: Seeding RNGs with %r" % _random_seed
```

to

```
print("I: Seeding RNGs with %r" % _random_seed)
```